# Service not receiving Intent while background thread blocked

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

I have two Android apps communicating with each other via intents. Let's call them **A** and **B** (not their real names).  Under normal circumstances, we have the following:

- Background thread of **A** sends Intent to **B**.
- Background thread of **A** blocks with Object.wait with 30 second timeout.
- **B** sends Intent to **A** using Context.startService.
- **A** receives Intent in Service.onStartCommand on main thread.
- **A** saves information from intent somewhere accessible from background thread.
- From main thread, **A** calls Object.notifyAll to release background thread.
- Background thread in **A** processes result.

This has been working fine for many years and with a particular customer in question, it's working for 98% of their 300 devices.

The problem now is this process is failing on a small number of devices.  The intent coming from **B** to **A** is being delayed while the background thread in **A** is blocked.  Once the background thread is no longer blocked (it has a 30 second timeout) the intent will be immediately received by **A** on the main thread, even though the main thread was never blocked.  So we have:

- Background thread of **A** sends Intent to **B**.
- Background thread of **A** blocks with Object.wait with 30 second timeout.
- **B** sends Intent to **A** using Context.startService.
- Background thread of **A** times out and no longer cares about Intent.
- **A** receives Intent in Service.onStartCommand on main thread.
- Intent in **A** is discarded because nothing is waiting for it anymore.
- Background thread of **A** will retry, starting the process again indefinitely.

App **B** doesn't appear to be the problem.  It is doing everything it should be in less than a second.  I have confirmed the main thread in **A** isn't blocked.  The UI remains responsive the whole time and I tried regularly running code on the main thread during this process to confirm it should be ready to receive the Intent.  This problem only started in the last few weeks and there has been no code changes.  I'm not aware of any changes in other apps running on the device but I would think they shouldn't cause this problem.  I'm not aware of any updates to the OS but they all seem to be running the same version.  So if this was a bug, I would expect to see it on all devices, not just a few.  Based on reports from the customer, after an extended period of time, and many retries of this code, it will suddenly work.  But then try the process again and it will get stuck again.

I'm hoping someone has seen something like this and/or could suggest possible causes of this behaviour.  I'm inclined to think it is environmental on the device but I don't know what could cause it. I'm completely stuck with this and I'm currently working on a workaround where I arbitrarily change the way this process works to achieve the same result, just in the hopes the problem will magically go away.

Comment: may be user forcefully stop background services .so check first.

Comment: @MukeshKumarSwami I have seen it happen myself looking at one of the devices in question and I didn't kill any services. I tried uninstalling various things as well with no effect.